# ReactJS NavLink activeClassName

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router

I want to rendered a NavLink with a active class when the route is the same that the current route. This is the code:

```
<NavLink className="nav-link-gdc" activeClassName="nav-link-gdc-selected" to="/home">HOME</NavLink>
```

The problem is that this only works when I reload the URL and I do not know how to trigger the change of the class when I click in the link.

EDIT:

My entry point:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <div>
        <HeaderControl />
        <MuiThemeProvider>
          <Switch>
            <Routes />
            <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Home} />
          </Switch>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app'),
);
```

All the links that I want to change the class when active are in the HeaderControl. How could I use the prop `location`?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Anybody looking in 2022+, the latest version of `react-router-dom` (currently 6.3.0 a the time of writing) has deprecated the `NavLink` `activeClassName`.  Instead, now, a callback function can be passed to `className` prop to pass in an active class style.  No more need for `location`.

```
<NavLink 
  className={nav => (nav.isActive ? "main-nav-link active" : "main-nav-link")} 
  to="/"
>
  Home
</NavLink
```

You can see that an argument is provided to that function with an `isActive` property.  The truthiness of this property can be used to dynamically add class names.

---

But a version with `location` could be done like this:

```
import { useLocation, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

const NavBar = () => {
  const location = useLocation()
    
  return (
    <NavLink 
      className={location.pathname === "/" ? "main-nav-link active" : "main-nav-link")} 
      to="/"
    >
      Home
    </NavLink>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
<NavLink className="nav-link-gdc" activeClassName={location.pathname !== "your pathname"? null : "nav-link-gdc-selected"} to="/home">HOME</NavLink>
```

Or don't I get your problem?

Comment: I tried this before but location is not defined cause the this NavLink is outside of a Route. I edited my question.